# How do I get the current active account?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In Google, you can sign into [multiple accounts](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) at the same time.

How do I get the current active account?  I thought I could use `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo` but that gets me the user of the signed-in profile.  Switching accounts within the same signed-in profile does not change the output of `chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo`.

Comment: I guess you'll have to download (XHR/fetch) and parse some google page which contains the active account name.

Comment: that'll probably be my last resort because Google could reposition the active account name that's on the page.  I'm really hoping that there's an API that I didn't see before.

Comment: this does not depend on chrome extension - you should try google APIs. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests